# "Error code 5: access denied" when trying to compile & run on Notepad++

Tags: c++, access-denied

I'm first day new to attempting to learn C++ as my first language. I went through a tutorial on how to get Cygwin and how to use Notepad++ to compile and run but when I try to run it it gives me this error:

```
NPP_EXEC: "C++ compile"
SET: G++ = C:\Programs\cygwin\bin
$(G++) = C:\Programs\cygwin\bin
NPP_SAVE: C:\Users\jpark\Desktop\hello.cpp
CD: C:\Users\<USER>\Desktop
Current directory: C:\Users\<USER>\Desktop
"C:\Game\cygwin\bin" -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11 -o "hello" "hello.cpp"
; about to start a child process: ""C:\Programs\cygwin\bin" -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11 -o "hello" "hello.cpp""
CreateProcess() failed with error code 5:
Access is denied.
```

I basically followed everything from this tutorial: http://www.edparrish.net/common/npp4c.html#system-path
followed everything perfectly, have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is your aim? Do you want to write the program on C++ or you want to understand how toolchain (preprocessor, compiler, linker) work?

Comment: Your tutorial does set `G++` variable to `g++.exe` location (`C:\cygwin\bin\g++.exe`), you set it to directory (`C:\Programs\cygwin\bin`). Change `SET: G++ = C:\Programs\cygwin\bin` to `SET: G++ = C:\Programs\cygwin\bin\g++.exe`